# How to Create Count down timer selecting Time from the Time picker input and show the difference of selected Time to current Time in angular

Tags: angular, timer, subscription, angular-bootstrap

This is my Typescript file

```
import { Time } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {  interval, Subscription, timer } from 'rxjs';
import {NgbTimeStruct} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';



@Component({
   selector: 'app-timer-app',
   templateUrl: './timer-app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./timer-app.component.css']
})

export class TimerAppComponent implements OnInit {

time : NgbTimeStruct= {hour: 13, minute: 30 , second: 25};
   
seconds = true;


constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.startInterval();
   console.log(this.time)
}
ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

stop(){
   this.countDown.unsubscribe();
}
start(){
     this.countDown = timer(0, this.tick).subscribe(() => --this.counter);
}


private timeinterval = interval;
private subscription!: Subscription;

public dateNow = new Date();
public dDay = this.model.getTime();
milliSecondsInASecond = 1000;
hoursInADay = 24;
minutesInAnHour = 60;
SecondsInAMinute = 60;

public timeDifference: any;
public secondsToDday: any;
public minutesToDday: any;
public hoursToDday: any;
public daysToDday: any;

private getTimeDifference() {
   this.dDay = this.time
   this.timeDifference = this.dDay - new Date().getTime();
   this.allocateTimeUnits(this.timeDifference);
}

private allocateTimeUnits(timeDifference: any) {
   this.secondsToDday = Math.floor(
    (timeDifference / this.milliSecondsInASecond) % this.SecondsInAMinute
);
 this.minutesToDday = Math.floor(
    (timeDifference / (this.milliSecondsInASecond * this.minutesInAnHour)) %
     this.SecondsInAMinute
);
 this.hoursToDday = Math.floor(
   (timeDifference /
     (this.milliSecondsInASecond *
      this.minutesInAnHour *
      this.SecondsInAMinute)) %
    this.hoursInADay
);
this.daysToDday = Math.floor(
  timeDifference /
    (this.milliSecondsInASecond *
      this.minutesInAnHour *
      this.SecondsInAMinute *
      this.hoursInADay)
);}


 stopInterval() {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
 }
 startInterval() {
   this.subscription = this.timeinterval(1000).subscribe(x => {
  //  console.log('get TD', this.timeDifference);
  this.getTimeDifference();
 
 });
 }
}
```

I'm facing the problem in my logic I don't know how to perform the logic for starting the count down after  selecting the  time from the input  when I select the time it is displaying in my variable but the count down is not started, and the count down gives no response please anyone can help me how I can do this

This is my HTML file where I want to show the count down

```
   <div class="container">
       <h1 class="text-success">Date Picker App</h1>
       <ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="time" [seconds]="seconds" ></ngb-timepicker>
       <hr>
       <pre> Seleted TIme Is : <strong>{{newTime}}</strong></pre>
  </div>

 <!--Count Down Timer DIsplay -->

  <div class="timer" *ngIf="model">
        <h2>Time Left</h2>

        <span id="hours"> {{hoursToDday}} </span>Hrs
        <span id="minutes"> {{minutesToDday}} </span>Min
        <span id="seconds"> {{secondsToDday}} </span>S <br>
        <div class="mt-3">
            <button  (click)="stopInterval()" class="btn btn-danger btn- 
            sm">Stop</button>
            <button  (click)="startInterval()" class="btn btn-info btn-sm 
            "id="resetbtn">Restart</button>
        </div>
```

[image: This is the error of my logic]

Comment: please create a stackblitz project with this issue.

Comment: Can you solve this issue

Comment: please create a stackblitz angular project and create the same codes there and put the link along with the question so that i can help you

Comment: when i will create the stackblitz project then i will send you link please kindly help me i m stuck in this problem from three days i not know how i can create count down timer using time picker

Comment: this is satackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-demo-vbqcpp?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code stackblitz link , [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-demo-u3mqa9?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbTimeStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 12';
  time: NgbTimeStruct = {
    hour: 2,
    minute: 50,
    second: 50
  };
  seconds = true;
  // timeData= this.time

  constructor() {}
  newInterVal: any;
  public timeDifference: any;
  public timeDiffereneRunning: NgbTimeStruct = null;
  public secondsToDday: any;
  public minutesToDday: any;
  public hoursToDday = this.time.hour;

  private getTimeDifference() {
    // this.dDay = this.time

    this.allocateTimeUnits();
  }
  private allocateTimeUnits() {
    let dateNow = new Date();

    let seconds = Math.floor(
      (new Date(this.timeDifference).getTime() - dateNow.getTime()) / 1000
    );
    let minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    let hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    let days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

    hours = hours - days * 24;
    minutes = minutes - days * 24 * 60 - hours * 60;
    seconds = seconds - days * 24 * 60 * 60 - hours * 60 * 60 - minutes * 60;

    this.hoursToDday = hours;

    this.minutesToDday = minutes;
    this.secondsToDday = seconds;
  }

  //  Start Stop Implementation

  ngOnInit() {
    this.startInterval();
    console.log(this.time);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {}

  stopInterval() {
    this.timeDiffereneRunning = {
      hour: this.hoursToDday,
      minute: this.minutesToDday,
      second: this.secondsToDday
    };
    clearInterval(this.newInterVal);
  }
  startInterval() {
    let time_diff = this.time;
    if (this.timeDiffereneRunning) {
      time_diff = this.timeDiffereneRunning;
    }
    let newDate = new Date(
      new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours() + time_diff.hour)
    );
    newDate = new Date(
      newDate.setMinutes(newDate.getMinutes() + time_diff.minute)
    );
    newDate = new Date(
      newDate.setSeconds(newDate.getSeconds() + time_diff.second)
    );
    this.timeDifference = newDate;
    console.log('diff', new Date(this.timeDifference));

    this.newInterVal = setInterval(() => {
      this.getTimeDifference();
    }, 1000);
  }
  getValue() {
    console.log(
      'Value Of Hour:',
      this.time.hour,
      'Value Of Minute:',
      this.time.minute,
      'Value Of Seconds:',
      this.time.second
    );
    //  console.log('Value Of Minute',this.time.minute)
    //  console.log('Value Of Seconds', this.time.second)
    //  console.log({data: this.time})
  }
}
```

Comment: no worries, kindly accept the answer if it is working

Comment: that you have to save the previous state into another variable and when the timediff calculates again, check older state exists. if then create the time diff that variable instead of UI bound variable.